# jQuery Dialog requires two clicks to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a jQuery dialog that need to open when i click the class .currentDay, this works but only on the second click. I'm thinking that i am initializing the modal on the first click and then opening it on the second.

I have tried different stuff to make it init and open, but i just cant seem to make it work. Hopefully someone on here can give me a hand.
this is the JavaScript that i currently have.

```js
        $('.currentDay').click(function () {
            var id = event.target.id;
            var url = '/Home/CalenderPartial/' + id;
            var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
            dialog.load(url, {},
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    dialog.dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        closeText: "",
                        width: $(window).width() - 300,
                        height: $(window).height() - 100,
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            dialog.remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
            return false;
        });
```

It also throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: dialog.dialog is not a function, but it is still working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to prevent default anchor behavior?

```
 $('.currentDay').click(function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
 });
```

All credit to earlyer post on github: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978800/jquery-working-on-second-click-only)

Comment: it doesnt change anything, still requires two clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me... please check **working example**

```js
$('.currentDay').click(function () {
            var id = event.target.id;
            var url = '/Home/CalenderPartial/' + id;
            var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
            dialog.load(url, {},
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    dialog.dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        closeText: "",
                        width: $(window).width() - 300,
                        height: $(window).height() - 100,
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            dialog.remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
            return false;
        });
```

```css
@import "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";
@import "/resources/demos/style.css";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="currentDay">BTN 1</button>
<button class="currentDay">BTN 2</button>
<button class="currentDay">BTN 3</button>
```

Comment: Hmm... i can see that your example works fine.
i tried changing my links to yours and then it doesnt work at all.